# Build Automatically is always on

Tags: java, eclipse, build

"Build Automatically" is always on even if I uncheck this option and restart Eclipse. What can be a cause of it? How can it be switched off reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted the question on Eclipse forum and got an answer. Preference Recorder caused this problem.

Here is the link:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1081373&goto=1743996&#msg_1743996